# SQL- selecting between duplicate rows by comparing field values

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, duplicates, data-warehouse

I was wondering if anyone can assist me.
I already manage to insert only the rows that are not duplicated

```
NSERT INTO temp_Log  
SELECT dq1.RowID,dq1.Action FROM DQLog dq1
    WHERE dq1.RowID 
    NOT IN (SELECT RowID FROM DQLog dq2
                group by dq2.RowID
                having count(*)>1
```

how ever i still need to filter the duplicated ones...
how can I select a row by a comparing the value between the duplicated rows in the same table?

```
RowID  Action 
 1     Reject
 1     Allow
 2     Allow
 2     Fix
```

In this case i will only need to insert the first (reject+allow= Reject) and last row (Allow+Fix = Fix).

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Is there any other combinations exists for `Action`? For example `reject+fix` or anything else?

Comment: i have 3 action ( reject,allow,fix) however reject will overrule all and fix overrule allow and if 2 rows have 'allow'then i can just pick one of them.

Comment: What happens when a`RowID` has `Reject` and `Fix` as action? Is it a possible scnario? If, Yes than which action should be inserted?

Comment: thats just the dqlog table. the merge will handle the proper action once the dqlog table is completed.the action for now it is just a flag for later.

Comment: Ok. But suppose RowId 3 has t actions.1)Reject and 2)Fix. In this case,which Action should be inserted along with RowId 3? Reject or Fix?

Comment: that would be reject. Fix will only overrule allow.

Comment: then my answer should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not possible that a Row_ID has Allow as Action more than once, then following query should work:

```
INSERT INTO temp_Log  
(SELECT distinct RowID,Action           
FROM DQLog 
Where Action = 'Reject'
UNION ALL
SELECT distinct RowID,Action           
FROM DQLog 
Where Action = 'Fix'
And RowID not in (Select distinct RowID from DQLog where Action='Reject')
)
;
```

**EDIT:**

I've mentioned 2 options in my comment. Here it how it goes:

**Option 1:**

Convert Action columns to lower case values.

```
Update DQLog set Action = Lower(Action);
```

The above query will convert all the values of `Action` in Lower case. Now you can run following query and it's done:

```
INSERT INTO temp_Log  
(SELECT distinct RowID,Action           
FROM DQLog 
Where Action = 'reject'
UNION ALL
SELECT distinct RowID,Action           
FROM DQLog 
Where Action = 'fix'
And RowID not in (Select distinct RowID from DQLog where Action='reject')
)
;
```

Hence your task is done and your redundant data is fixed too.

```
Option 2:
```

Just add the all possible variation of `Fix` and `Reject` in where clause of my main query as follows:

```
INSERT INTO temp_Log  
(SELECT distinct RowID,Action           
FROM DQLog 
Where Action = 'Reject' or Action='reject'
UNION ALL
SELECT distinct RowID,Action           
FROM DQLog 
Where Action = 'Fix' or Action = 'fix'
And RowID not in (Select distinct RowID from DQLog where Action='Reject'or Action='reject')
)
;
```

I will advice you to go for `Option 1` !

Hope it helps!

Comment: I will give it a try now, i will let you know ! thanks mate !

Comment: My microsoft sql server management studio says group_concat is not a recognized built-in function. i will try to find the correspondent one, but thanks mate. it already gave me an idea

Comment: Microsoft Sql Server? You've tagged MySql buddy. That's why I used Group_Concat.  Please tag the RDBMS properly.

Comment: The task is hard in sql server compare to Oracle or MySQL. Can you please tell me the version of your Sql server? I can find solution accordingly.

Comment: Sorry for the wrongly putting the tag, it wont happen next time. thanks for addresing that error.

Comment: I am using Microsof SQLserver 2012.
microsoft Server management studio version 11.0.2100.60

Comment: try the @GordonLinoff's solution. It'll work I guess.

Comment: Sorry aboout that, it was already 4 am last time checked.
@Harshil i used your code but some of the non duplicated rows were also included, but im changing the code to better suit the purpose, thank you very much !

Comment: @GordonLinoff's 
Hi Gordon, thank you for your time, your code seems quite neat however my server management studio does not recognize the " SUM(dq1.Action = 'Allow') " it says that "Expecting ',', AND or OR. BUt im also trying to figure it out. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @Hashil almost perfect mate! the fix is overruling the allow just as its suppose to do !, but when there is fix and reject, he is duplicating the rows.
this is the result
![result](https://imgur.com/a/WRx0D).

Comment: The code is fine. The problem is in your data . You very `fix` and `Fix` both as Action which are not same for SQL engine. SQL engine will take those two as different Actions and I've only included `Fix` in my code as I'm not aware of this redundancy. Same thing goes for `Reject` & ``reject.

Comment: In this schenario, you've 2 option. (1) Convert whole Action column into Lower case. This is recommended by me as it'll remove  the redundancy from your table. (2) Add `fix` and `reject` in my query. Choice is yours.

Comment: Thanks mate ! I did not realize that ! that was perfect !

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, then kindly MARK it as Answer and upvote it. That'll be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I would phrase this as:

```
INSERT INTO temp_Log (?, ?)  -- put the column names here
    SELECT dq1.RowID,
           (CASE WHEN MIN(dq1.Action) = MAX(d1.Action) THEN MIN(dq1.Action)
                 WHEN SUM(dq1.Action = 'Allow') > 0 AND SUM(dq1.Action = 'Reject') > 0 THEN 'Reject'
                 WHEN SUM(dq1.Action = 'Allow') > 0 AND SUM(dq1.Action = 'Fix') > 0 THEN 'Fix'
                 ELSE ??  -- your rules don't specify
           END) as Action
    FROM DQLog dq1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM DQLog d12 
                      WHERE dq1.RowID = dq2.RowID
                     )
GROUP BY dq1.RowId;
```

Notes:

- List the columns when doing an insert.  This is a best practice and will prevent coding errors in the future.
- This includes the two rules you specify.  However, there are other cases you don't specify.  Hence, the `ELSE ??`.
- `NOT EXISTS` is better than `NOT IN` for two reasons.  First, `NOT IN` will filter out all rows if even one row in the subquery is `NULL`.  Second, `NOT EXISTS` should be faster than having an aggregation subquery.

Comment: THank you gordon, i will give it a try!

Comment: Yeah... sum() works fine here I guess. Never had a thought of this kind of approach. (+1 from me).